# Database Schema For Storing Emails

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I need to save incoming and outgoing *emails* from an application in a MySQL database server.

It used to be simple to do in that all that needed to be tracked was the *from address*, *to address*, *subject*, and *body*, but now I need to support multiple *to addresses* and *cc addresses* in a single *email*.

I am struggling with the ideal schema (or structure) and query needed to do this the most efficiently. I started thinking of having one table for the *email*, another for the to *addresses*, associated back as a many-to-one relationship, and another table for the *cc addresses* also associated back with a many-to-one relationship and simply running three separate read queries to get the *email*, *to addresses*, and *cc addresses* to display on the front-end when the saved *email* gets opened.

Is this the most efficient way to achieve this at this point or is there a better and more efficient solution?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420264/creating-a-threaded-private-messaging-system-like-facebook-and-gmail/6425511#6425511 and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541302/thread-messaging-system-database-schema-design/6542556#6542556 To, CC, and BCC are all just potentially a recipient type code added to the recipient table in these answers.